# A good approach for saving Strapi logs into a log file?

Tags: logging, strapi

I am looking for a simple approach in order to store the logs from my Strapi app into a file rather than just receiving them in the console.
From documentations I couldn't find a good way to achieve that. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Well you can use any of the loggers of your choice like [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston), [Simple Node Logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-node-logger) Etc. I've personally used [Simple Node Logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-node-logger).

So, firstly create a `helpers` folder in the root of your `strapi` project. Then create a `logger.js` file in it. Add the following code to the logger file.

```js
// helpers/logger.js
const simpleLogger = require('simple-node-logger');

const logger = simpleLogger.createRollingFileLogger({
  logDirectory: 'logs/',
  fileNamePattern: 'strapi_log_<DATE>.log',
  dateFormat: 'YYYY.MM.DD',
});

module.exports = logger;
```

Next, create the `/logs` folder in the root of your project. Finally, require the logger in your `controller` or `service` file and log messages to the log files. `Simple Node Logger` will handle the process of rolling log files and log filenames on daily basis for you.

```js
// api/restaurants/controller/index.js
const logger = require('../../../helpers/logger');

module.exports = {
  async someFindMethod(ctx){
    logger.info('Log information to log files');
    logger.error('Log error to log files');
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

###### Output

```log
## logs/strapi_log_2021.10.14.log
11:14:36.048 INFO  Log information to log files 
11:14:36.048 INFO  Log error to log files
```

###### Sidenote:

To avoid server restarts on changes in log file, you need to ignore the folder by adding `watchIgnoreFiles: ['**/logs/**']` to your `config/server.js` file in `Strapi v3` ([Check here](https://docs-v3.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#server)) or to you `config/admin.js` file if your on `Strapi v4` ([Check here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/required/admin-panel.html#available-options)).

Comment: To avoid constant strapi server restarts with each change of the log file, you need to add `watchIgnoreFiles` to your /config/admin.js (more [here](https://forum.strapi.io/t/change-file-without-triggering-a-reload-of-strapi/4026/8)).

Comment: Yep, @Speedy. Thanks for the comment. I'll add this to the answer to make it more meaningful to others.